# Does ccls supports a project-wide call hierachy?

Tags: emacs, call-hierarchy

Nowadays I'm trying to adapt new popular features called LSP(language Server Protocol) into my emacs. In the middle of that I found that some of those language server like as ccls, cquery can support a feature "call hierarchy". But I wonder whether it can find call hierarchy in a huge project like as Linux kernel. Unless it has, then I'd like to know if there is an another way to figure out a call hierarchy in a project. 
Could you give me some advice, please?

Thanks.